# Application not quit when sending QApplication::exit or QApplication::quit

Tags: c++, qt

I have wrote an app in Qt and C++.

the `main` contain is calling a MainUi class and in case of issue during the Main UI init, the MainUi class is calling the `QApplication::exit()`. The Application seems close at first but the icon is still present in the dock which mean that the application is not really quit.

Here is the code used by the class MainUI.

```
void MainUI::InitResult() {
    if(error != ERROR_NONE) {
        QApplication::processEvents();
        Splashscreen->Ui_Splashscreen_failure();
        Timer timer(4000);
        Splashscreen->close();
        emit error_init();
    }
    else
    {
        QApplication::processEvents();
        Puls_Splashscreen->close();
        QApplication::setOrganizationName(COMPANY_NAME);
        QApplication::setApplicationName(PRODUCT_NAME);
        InitUserInterface();
    }
}
```

the *main.cpp* is managing to instantiate the MainUI class but do not have any `close()`/`quit()` action

```
MainUI MyWindow(*DeviceFramework);
QObject::connect(&MyWindow, SIGNAL(error_init()),&app, SLOT(quit()));
MyWindow.InitApplication();
return app.exec();
```

`InitApplication` is enabling the management. At the end of the treatment the MainUI receive a signal and the slot `InitResult()` to treat the error. I have created another signal `init_error()` which is emitted by `InitResult()` to inform about an issue and ask to close the app.

Any idea ?

Comment: The problem is probably in calling `QApplication::exit()` **before** the `QApplication::exec()` is called.